# Paypal in WebView = White Page (not an https issue)

Tags: android, paypal

Simple android app, with WebView, and when I open any url of PayPal site, in i.e.:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.paypal.com/ua/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_run-check-cookie-submit&redirectCmd=_login-submit");
```

it shows white page

I followed recomendation of filtering JS
http://webdevsys.com/paypalBlankPage.htm

I skip this JS in "onLoadResource" section of my app Java code:

```
...
onLoadResource(WebView view, String url){
            if(url.contains("pp_jscode_080706.js")
                    ){
            } else { 
                  super.onLoadResource(view, url);
               }            
}
...
```

but it didnt help.

JS is enabled,

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I dont have settings for opening browser
in ShouldOverrideUrlLoading, so all urls and redirects are internal

It's not an https issue, I've even added (but have no errors):

```
@Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
            SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            android.util.Log.i("!!!!", "ssl error = " + "SSL Error received: "+ error.getPrimaryError());
            handler.proceed();
        }
```

I have API min level 8 in manifest, tested on real device 4.1.1 and emulator 4.2.2

Comment: Do you have a way to see how you request looks like (on wire)? Maybe use Wireshark on another computer on the network (with promiscuous mode) or run it on a computer used as a hotspot itself. Maybe Paypal can't identify your user-agent resolution and leaves the size on 1 pixel.

Comment: @selalerer, I'll try to set standart useragent, as now I have a custom one, - "Android myapp". on ios by the way all wirks with custom useragent, even without words like iphone/ipad.

Comment: @selalerer, It works without user-agent ! Thank You, and please paste your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy to hear it works. It was no more than an educated guess :-)

Comment: It was in my mind too, as option, but i reject this, as i have already "android" word in my custom UA :) Btw, now my final useragent is: 

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; de-de; HTC_Wildfire_A3333 Build/FRG83D) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1; MyApp

I need both words "Myapp" and "Android" for serverside checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Paypal can't identify your user-agent resolution and leaves the size on 1 pixel.

Comment: Btw, now my final useragent is: 

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; de-de; HTC_Wildfire_A3333 Build/FRG83D) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1; MyApp

I need both words "Myapp" and "Android" for serverside checks, so now UA has them and PayPal works.

Comment: I don't know how Paypal is doing their server side, but I know there are databases sold out there that holds mapping between user agent strings and resolution (and other properties of the mobile device). If this is what they use, a more complete and well known user agent is required from the client for them to correctly identify it.

Comment: it would be nice if they render small/big webpage somehow at least

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the webview is

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and not wrap content.

That will correct the problem.